# Отслеживание "слайдинга" на телефонах при помощи jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Такой вопрос - как отследить событие "слайдинга" на сайте?
Т.е. (честно сказать не знаю как это правильно называется, по этому я и загуглить не могу нормально) когда пользователь проводит пальцем по экрану смартфона, например у меня есть в мобильной версии сайта мобильное меню и я хочу что бы когда пользователь проводил по нему влево - оно скрывалось. Как называется это событие? я знаю что то подобное используется в слайдерах бутстрапа судя по всему

Comment: swipe называется. touchstart – mousedown, touchmove – mousemove, touchend, touchcancel – mouseup. В jQuery Mobile более расширенный список событий - swipe, swipeleft, swiperight и т.д.

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов ага, спасибо, но ещё тогда вопрос такой - если у меня подключена просто jquery будет ли она конфликтовать с jquery mobile ?? если их подключить вместе